# Symfony 3.3 mystyle.css cant be found

Tags: symfony

After investing quite some time on this problem I still cannot get this to work. In my base.html.twig file I link to the mystyle.css file, located at css/style.css inside the web directory, as follows:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    <link href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
{% endblock %}
```

I then extend the base.html.twig file in my template files, when I navigate to any of these files I get the following error message in my browser console:

```
GET http://testsymf/css/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED
```

My server config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\test3\web\app_dev.php"
ServerName testsymf
<Directory /xampp/htdocs/test3/web>
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Permission problem, check your permission level.

read more [Setting up or Fixing File Permissions](https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/setup/file_permissions.html)